# Differentiability of a simple value function driven by a diffusion

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Consider a diffusion given by, 
$d X_t = \mu(X_t) dt + \sigma(X_t) dB_t$

$X_0 = x$.

Suppose the functions $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are as follows -

$f(x) = \mu(x) = \sigma(x) = \begin{cases} 2 & \text{ if } x \ge 0 \\
1 & \text{ if } x < 0 \end{cases}
$

The purpose of $f(x)$ will be clear in a moment.

By Nakao(1972) we know that there exists a strong solution. Now, suppose I am interested in computing the following -

$v(x) = \mathbb{E}^x \int_0^\infty e^{-t} f(X_t) d t $

I know how to do it mechanically. We have the following two DEs:
\begin{align} v(x) - 2 v'(x) -2v"(x) -2 = 0 & \text{ if } x >0 \\
v(x) - v'(x) - \frac{1}{2} v"(x) -1 =0 & \text{ if } x < 0 
\end{align}

Now, I will solve these 2 simple DEs. Each solution will have 2 constants to be determined. I will use the fact that $v(\infty) = 2$ and $v(-\infty) = 1$ to kill one constant on either side. Then, I will use continuity and differentiability (smooth-pasting) at $0$ to obtain the other 2 constants.

In doing so, however, I have assumed that $v$ is differentiable at $0$. I can prove that $v$ is continuous at $0$. But I do not know how to make the argument for differentiability. This sort of a question comes up often for applied people working with stochastic control and the "standard" method is to assume that it is smooth and then use a "verification theorem". Assuming I want to avoid that, what could be a direct way to prove differentiability?

Comment: Is your concern essentially that there is a 1 dimensional subspace of solutions to the DE system which satisfy the appropriate BCs and continuity at zero, and you don't know how to select the appropriate one?

Comment: Yes. From what I know, the appropriate condition comes from the fact that $v(x)$ is differentiable at $0$. But I don't know of any argument that says so.

Comment: You should view your ODE as $v(x)-(1+H(x))v'(x)-(1/2+3/2H(x))v''(x)=1+H(x)$ where $H$ is the Heaviside step function. One should be able to define a weak solution to this ODE in an appropriate sense, and from there you can try to argue that such a solution must be sufficiently regular (perhaps $C^1$). The difficulty that I see is that the *leading* coefficient is discontinuous.

Comment: This sounds very interesting and relevant. Do you know of a reference I can look at for weak solutions?

Comment: Unfortunately I learned this stuff in a class taught somewhat loosely out of Evans PDE, which does not cover it very thoroughly. That said, I see how to work around the difficulty now: you can rewrite as $v''(x)+\frac{1+H(x)}{1/2+3/2H(x)}v'(x)-\frac{1}{1/2+3/2H(x)} v(x)=-\frac{1+H(x)}{1/2+3/2H(x)}$. You can simplify the quotients of step functions to get $v''(x)+(2-H(x))v'(x)+(-2+3/2H(x))v(x)=H(x)-2$.

Comment: Now multiply by a smooth compactly supported function $w$, integrate over the line, and integrate the second derivative term by parts. You get $\int_{\mathbb{R}} -v' w'+(2-H)v'w+(-2+3/2H)vw=\int_{\mathbb{R}} (H-2)w$. So now the problem can be formulated in some Sobolev space requiring just one weak derivative (since this new integral equation only involves $v'$, not $v''$). The problem that I see now is that $v$ can't be $L^p$ for any finite $p$, since it does not vanish at infinity...

Comment: I don't understand the stuff you are doing, so I will need to read up about it. But if your only  concern is that $v$ does not vanish at $\infty$, I am more than happy to make it vanish at $\infty$ if that makes your job easier.

Comment: If it vanishes at infinity, then you can use Lax-Milgram to get existence/uniqueness of weak solutions, but unfortunately Sobolev space theory only gives you Holder continuity for free...not sure how to fix that to try to get $C^1$.

Comment: Intuitively, the highest derivative has the least regularity in the equation, so any discontinuities (or worse) can be rolled into it. In this case the integral of the Heaviside function (the worst discontinuity you have here) is continuous, so the *first* derivative should be continuous while the second derivative should be discontinuous (and nonexistent at zero). I'm just not sure how to iron out the details of that argument.

Comment: Actually, now I see: if you were able to find *one* continuously differentiable solution with zero boundary conditions, Lax-Milgram tells you that it is (a representative of) the only weak solution that exists. This is despite the fact that *a priori* you only get $C^{0,1/2}$ regularity (which is basically halfway between continuous and continuously differentiable). Thus in some sense the coefficients of your equation are slightly nicer than they would be in the worst possible case. That seems to be against the spirit that you wanted to follow, though...

Comment: Thanks Ian. I will read up stuff on what you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have figured out a way to prove that $v(x)$ is differentiable. The idea is to use the sort of techniques used in viscosity solution for optimal control. I will give a sketch of the argument below. My proof hardly makes use of the structure given above. In fact, I think, for a piecewise Lipschitz, bounded $\mu,\sigma$ and $f$, the same reasoning should hold. I only need $\sigma$ to be bounded from below by a strictly positive number.

By Krylov (Ch 1, Theorem 5), $v$ is $C^2$ everywhere except $0$. Also, $v'_-(0)$ and $v'_+(0)$ exist. Suppose, $0 < v'_-(0) < v'_+(0)$. Pick a number $\rho$ between $(v'_-(0),v'_+(0))$ and define,

\begin{align*}
\psi_\epsilon(x) = v(0) + \rho(y-x) + \frac{1}{2\epsilon} (y-x)^2
\end{align*}

Observe that $x=0$ is a minimum point of $v(x)-\psi(x)$ and $\psi$ is $C^2$.

Now, using pretty much the same proof as in Pham (2009) for viscosity supersolution with the only modification required at the end, we can prove that the following is true -

\begin{align*}
r v(0) - \left[\underline{\mu} \psi'(0) + \frac{\underline{\sigma}^2}{2} \psi''_\epsilon(0)+\underline{f}\right] \ge 0
\end{align*}

Where $\underline{\mu}$, $\underline{\sigma}$ ,$\underline{f}$ are the global lower bounds.

Now, taking $\epsilon$ to $0$ gives us the desired contradiction as $\psi_\epsilon '' = \frac{1}{\epsilon}$.

A similar argument can be made with the techniques for subsolution, once again, found in Pham(2009).